# SQL Trigger error (ORA-00942: table or view does not exist)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I create this sql trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER create_event_from_task BEFORE INSERT ON llx_projet_task
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO llx_actioncomm (priority, fulldayevent, location, label, fk_element, elementtype, fk_project, datep, datef, percentage, note)
    SELECT 0, 0, '', 'prova', id, 'project_task', fk_project, date_start, date_end, progress, description
    FROM inserted;
END;
/
```

But when I execute says this errors:

```
Errors: TRIGGER CREATE_EVENT_FROM_TASK
Line/Col: 2/2 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 4/7 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unless you have a table called `inserted`, Oracle doesn't has one built in.  The error message seems pretty clear.

Comment: Did you check table named "inserted" is in the same schema with your trigger? If "inserted" table exists maybe you should give a `grant` to it for your trigger to detect.

Comment: Assuming that you are a SQL Server user (as noted below), be careful working with triggers--Oracle and SQL Server have significantly different mechanisms for how triggers behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it got this error because of the select query inside the trigger. Check if the user which called the trigger has the grant to execute select from the "inserted" table.

https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist/

**Ora-00942** means you are attempting to execute an SQL statement that references a table or view which does not exist. There are several possible causes for the “table or view does not exist” error, including:

```
1) Referencing a table or view that does not exist
2) Using an unauthorized synonym
3) Using an expression of view where a table is required
4) Attempting to use a table without proper permission or privilege
```

Answer (score 0):

`inserted` is part of SQL Server.  I think you want:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO llx_actioncomm (priority, fulldayevent, location, label, fk_element, elementtype, fk_project, datep, datef, percentage, note)
        SELECT 0, 0, '', 'prova', :new.id, 'project_task', 
               :new.fk_project, :new.date_start, :new.date_end, 
               :new.progress, :new.description
        FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: or simply `insert into (...) values (..., :new.fk_project, :new.date_start, ...)`